# Cannot find module './routes/<jsfile>' while runnign Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I have docker dockerize node application. 
But when I'm running image ,it gives me below error message :

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './routes/viewInprogressDetails'
```

**ProjectFolderStructure**

> --node_modules    :express    :align-text --views     :dashboard.html     :login.html
>      --routes     :dashboard.js   :viewInProgressDetails.js --package.json --app.js --route.js

**app.js** and **node_module folder** are present under same project directory.

Below are the instruction I'm using to build docker:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node app.js
```

Can you please guide here where its getting wrong? If I run app locally it's running fine.

Comment: Are the filenames in the import part exactly the same? windows is not case sensitive but not linux, if you are using linux containers maybe this could be the problem.

Comment: Hi Oscar, Nice suggestion.  I do find there is case mismatch. I'm fixing it and will try to run image. Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I added the comment as response.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames are case sensitive in Linux but not in windows.
If you are using Linux containers maybe this could be the problem.